# How to handle animations between react components

Tags: reactjs

I've been looking at ember's liquid fire again (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8aF-7-_cE8) and attempting to replicate a similar workflow with react. Unfortunately my attempts haven't amounted to much.

So my question is in 2 parts:

1) If a DOM element is represented in two separate components (for example a link in a list in one component becomes a title in another component), what is the react way to transition this element from component to component. I realise this isn't literally feasible using react, but I mean transition in the superficial sense.

2) Using react's native animation tools (or 3rd party libraries), is there a way to separate component state transitions from the actual render method.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion), it is a very powerful library for performing animations in react. Here are two simple examples using it: [chat-heads](http://chenglou.github.io/react-motion/demos/demo1-chat-heads), [draggable-balls](http://chenglou.github.io/react-motion/demos/demo2-draggable-balls)